# Transactional IO operations using .Net Core

Tags: io, .net-core, transactional

Is there a way to implement platform independent transactional I/O operations using .Net Core?
In pure .Net world we can use Transactional NTFS, but that is not an option.

Comment: Can you give an example of what exactly you need? the question is quite broad otherwise. Do not that transactional ntfs isn't recommended by microsoft even on windows.

Comment: I need a way to do file system operations in one transaction with database operations.

Answer (score 1):

Use transient transaction using the System.Transactions namespaces in .NET. In .NET Core 2.1, SQL client and EF Core fully support integrating into ambient transactions. See EF Core's [Using System.Transaction documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#using-systemtransactions).

You can then use enlistments to add custom logic that supports commit and rollback functionality. See [Transaction.EnlistVolatile documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transaction.enlistvolatile?view=netcore-2.1) and a [live sample code](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/7ce47778b4a5238db133cd0d4ffc3aa2695e406c/src/dotnet/TransactionalAction.cs) used in the `dotnet install tool` logic.

There is a package on NuGet ([TxFilemanager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TxFileManager/)) that implements common file operations using System.Transations but its site on CodePlex is now down, however there are forks on GitHub like [this one](https://github.com/glotoff/transactionalfilemgr) containing the source code which should help implementing these actions.